# How to make server ip property driven in karaf

Tags: apache-camel, apache-karaf

I am deploying a jar in karaf .

My jar consists of a camel route

### Copyin only the route part :

```
                from("file:/app/billing/billingip/HOBSRating/data/mediation/voice/input?include=USAGE_VOICE.*.txt")
                .doTry()        
              .log("#########The Camel Header before loading into kafka topic ######## :${headers}")
              .log("#########The Camel Body  before loading into kafka topic  ######## :${body}")
              .to("kafka:172.20.211.201:9092?topic=VoiceStream&zookeeperHost=172.20.211.201&zookeeperPort=9092&serializerClass=kafka.serializer.StringEncoder")
             /* .to("kafka:${kafkaserver}?topic=DataStream&zookeeperHost=${zookeeperHost}&zookeeperPort=${zookeeperport}&serializerClass=kafka.serializer.StringEncoder")*/
              .to("file:/app/billing/billingip/HOBSRating/data/mediation/voice/success")
              .doCatch(Exception.class)
              .log("########The exception message is             ####### :${exception.message}")
              .log("########The stack trace of the exception is  ####### :${exception.stacktrace}")
              .to("file:/app/billing/billingip/HOBSRating/data/mediation/voice/error")
              .log("###############    End of Voice Cdr to Kafka Topic Route      ################")
```

Currently ,I am hard coding the kafka server credentials but i want to make this property file driven.

Answer (score 0):

Read about Camel's property placeholder where you can externalize configuration and refer to them from your Camel routes: http://camel.apache.org/using-propertyplaceholder.html

Comment: Ahh for *** sake please spend more time learning how to ask a question on stackoverflow where your question is readable and understandable. Dont just copy a bunch of code/stacktaces to a comment section that is unreadable,